# Преобразовать void* в vector - SQLite Callback

Tags: c++, vector, sqlite3, void

Возникла проблема в извлечении данных из `SELECT` запроса в SQLite.

Метод для выполнения запроса:

```
template < typename Result, typename Errmsg >
bool SQLite::Select (std::string sql, Errmsg &errmsg, Result &result){

if (this->errn != SQLITE_OK) {
    return false;
}

int rc = sqlite3_exec(this->db, sql.c_str(), this->callback, (void*) &result, NULL);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

Статическая Callback функция для записи этого результата в `static vector`:

```
int SQLite::callback (void* &res, int num, char** data, char** col) {

std::map<const char *, std::string> buffer;
std::string key;
std::string val;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    key = col[i];
    val = data[i] ? data[i] : "NULL";
    buffer[key.c_str()] = val;
}
reinterpret_cast<std::vector <std::map<const char *, std::string>>> (res).push_back(buffer);
return 0;
}
```

Может кто подскажет как это решить!?

Для справки! Есть класс `Offers`, создал статическую переменную Query типа вектор и пробовал записать данные в callback функции (код выше) с помощью такой записи:

```
::Offers::Query.push_back(buffer);
```

Но компилятор меня послал за дровами следующей ошибкой:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc2FAOAz.o: в функции «SQLite::callback(void*, int, char**, char**)»:
sqlite.cpp:(.text+0x1ab): неопределённая ссылка на «Offers::Query[abi:cxx11]»
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В результате:

```
using  Ptrv =  std::vector <std::map<const char*, std::string>>*;
reinterpret_cast<Ptrv>(res)->push_back(buffer);
```

РАБОТАЕТ! Так же как и более простой код в стиле "C":

```
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> *r = (std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>>*)res;
```

Но! Если в buffer и в передаваемой переменной, ключ будет определен как (const char *):

```
std::map<const char*, std::string> buffer;
```

В buffer записывается только последние данные в цикле for, а в переменную которая была передана в качестве указателя вообще мусор какой-то. Вот что программа в этом случае выводит:

```
/*вывод col[i] и data[i] или key и val*/
id = 1
name = Lemberg Premium Горбуша
price_id = 1
distrib_id = 2
url_id = 1
cat_id = 3
manufact_id = 1
/*содержимое buffer*/
Перебор внутри callback:
manufact_id : 1
/*содержимое r (переменная которая передавалась)*/
Перебор внутри Offers:
����%V : 1
```

Если же вместо (const char*) указать тип std::string то все записывается как надо. А все потому что (const char*) это указатель на переменную col[i] и после завершения callback функции col[i] удаляется из памяти. Соответственно ссылаться не на что.

Были сделаны правки и доведено до рабочего состояния!

**Callback функция:**

```
/*static*/ int SQLite::callback (void* res, int num, char** data, char** col) {

std::map<std::string, std::string> buffer;
std::string key;
std::string val;

for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    key = col[i];
    val = data[i] ? data[i] : "NULL";
    buffer[key] = val;
}

std::cout << "Перебор внутри callback:" << std::endl;
for(auto& item : buffer) {
std::cout << item.first << " : " << item.second << std::endl; 
}
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> *r = (std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>>*)res;
r->push_back(b);
return 0;
}
```

**Функция в которой вызывается Callback**

```
bool SQLite::Select (std::string sql, char** errmsg, void* result){

if (this->errn != SQLITE_OK) {
    return false;
}

int rc = sqlite3_exec(this->db, sql.c_str(), this->callback,result, NULL);

if (rc != SQLITE_OK) {
    return false;
}

return true;
}
```

**Пример выполнения запроса**

```
bool Offers::add_offer (GtkWidget *widget) {
std::cout << "Action = add new offer" << std::endl;
char **errmsg;
std::vector<std::map<std::string, std::string>> r;
if (sql.Select("SELECT * FROM offers", errmsg, &r) == false) {
    std::cout << "Error request..." << std::endl;
}
else {
    std::cout << "Перебор внутри Offers:" << std::endl;
    for(auto& item : r[0]) {
        std::cout << item.first << " : " << item.second << std::endl; 
    }
}
return true;
}
```

**Вывод программы в Терминале** (в Windows это Консоль)

```
Перебор внутри callback:
cat_id : 3
distrib_id : 2
id : 1
manufact_id : 1
name : Lemberg Premium Горбуша
price_id : 1
url_id : 1

Перебор внутри Offers:
cat_id : 3
distrib_id : 2
id : 1
manufact_id : 1
name : Lemberg Premium Горбуша
price_id : 1
url_id : 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Невозможно преобразовать void* к какому то вектору. Можно преобразовать на указатель на вектор:

```
using  Ptrv =  std::vector <std::map<const char*, std::string>>*;
reinterpret_cast<Ptrv>(res)->push_back(buffer);
```

Comment: Копал ответ по этому поводу, вот что получилось:
`std::vector<std::map<const char *, std::string>> *r = (std::vector<std::map<const char *, std::string>>*)res;`

Запись в вектор идет, НО! В буфер записываются данные, проверил через `.size()`, по указателю тоже пишутся (опять таки `.size()`). Но например `r[0]["id"]` ничего нет... Хотя `.size()` говорит что 1!